# Unable to connect to database in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I actually deleted the previous connection and the models from my project and added them again.  However, now I can't connect to the database again. I verified the connection strings in all the web.config and app.config, but they are the same.

`Web.config`:

```
<add name="AuthenticationAppEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MyPC;Initial Catalog=AuthenticationApp;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Another `web.config`:

```
<add name="AuthenticationAppEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MyPC;Initial Catalog=AuthenticationApp;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

`App.config`:

```
<add name="AuthenticationAppEntities"  
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MyPC;Initial Catalog=AuthenticationApp;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have no idea what could be wrong there. Any help?

When I enable Common Language Runtime Exception, I get this error :

> '(db.Table).Local' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Is there any specific error you are getting ? That would help us get to the root cause faster.

Comment: What is that &quot entity doing there? Should that be `'`? Or something messed it up when you pasted it?

Comment: @Pradip: I am not getting any error message in my error console but in my Output console I have this: 'A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll'  and when I watch the db.Table in a query, I have this : '(db.Table).Local' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'.  I am blocked with this since 2 days

Comment: @HanletEscaño:  I always have &quot in the connection strings. I am pretty sure it is good, unless if I am missing something here.

Comment: @tabby, you are getting this when you are trying to open the connection ? or when you build the solution ?

Comment: @Pradip: When trying to open the connection.

Comment: I have added the error I get in the question

Comment: Why does it says "provider connection string=&quot" in your Conn String ? Could you try changing the &quot to "  and try again ? (Escape characters might be required)

Comment: <add name="AuthenticationAppEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='';Data Source=ASTEKLT85;Initial Catalog=AuthenticationApp;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @Pradip: you mean change it as above?

Comment: @Pradip:  I changed it as above but I get 'Keyword not supported: 'data source'.' error.

Comment: Change the Provider Connection String as shown below :

Comment: provider connection string='Data Source=MyPC;Initial Catalog=AuthenticationApp;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework'"

Comment: catch the first chance exception to find what operation is invalid?

Comment: @Pradip: Now I am getting this: '(db.Table).Local' threw an exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' or the query keeps on running without any results

Comment: Lets try one more thing; Try this one and let me know if this works or not. <add name="AuthenticationAppEntities" 
connectionString="Data Source=ASTEKLT85;Initial Catalog=AuthenticationApp;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @Pradip: Just to be sure, I change the connection string in all the web.config where it appears and app.config, right?

Comment: @Pradip:  In my Output console, it says: The 'data source' keyword is not supported.

Comment: :( I have to check further then.

Comment: @Pradip:  oh ok.  I think I will just delete all the connection and models and add them up again.

Comment: Fresh start is always is good. Try and let me know if that works out or not.

Comment: No luck. I am lost about what to do now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362657/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-express-using-entityframework-solved

Answer (score 0):

check these links, it may help you.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1749216.aspx?Code+First+Entity+Framework+not+creating+tables+in+the+database

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/299466/Code-First-Entity-Framework-not-creating-tables-in

[How to handle System.InvalidOperationException in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525007/how-to-handle-system-invalidoperationexception-in-entity-framework)

I am using connection string something like below

```
<add name="AuthenticationAppEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MyPC;Initial Catalog=AuthenticationApp;User ID=xyz;Password=Password@1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is of no help.